# Results in order with first ajax but inside for loop order randomly changed. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is weird really for me . I am not able to understand why this is happening, I want someone to explain this please.

Okay, I am running One ajax call in which i am calling [data] and running it through a for loop where i am getting all the database values then i am running another ajax call to check the other condition where i am getting other value. Everything is working great as i want. The problem is the order in which i am getting the values after the success of the second ajax is random. Which is totally not understandable.

In my first ajax call i am getting results in right order i.e DESC order.

Please explain me why.

```
function get_filter_data(val) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "filter_data.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:'rating='+val,
                success: function(data){

                    var str = '';
                    var cide = $('#cSessionid').val();
                    //console.log(cide+'-session-id');

                    for(var i in data)
                    {
                        var ide = data[i].id;
                        var username = data[i].username;
                        var u_name = username.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
                            return letter.toUpperCase();
                        });
                        var email = data[i].email;
                        var ref_number = data[i].ref_number;
                        var rating = data[i].rating;
                        var title = data[i].review_title;
                        var desc = data[i].review_desc;
                        var pubdate = data[i].pubdate;


                        //console.log(data[i].id+'-first-id');
                         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "add_edit_delete.php",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cache: false,
                             data: {
                                username: username,
                                u_name: u_name,
                                email: email,
                                ref_number : ref_number,
                                rating : rating,
                                title : title,
                                desc : desc,
                                pubdate : pubdate,
                                ppid : ide
                                 },
                            success: function(data){

                                var eip = data.ipadt;

                                 if(eip === cide){ 

                            var ddc = '<div class="editndeletebox"><a href="#" class="editreviewn"><span>Edit</span></a><a class="deletereviewn" href="#"><span>Delete</span></a></div>';

                         }else{

                            var ddc = '<span></span>';
                         }

                        str += '<div class="review pageable-item-js item clearfix" data-reviewmid="57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be">';
                        str +=      '<div class="user-info clearfix">';
                        str +=          '<div class="user-review-name clearfix"><a class="user-review-name-link" rel="nofollow" title="go to ' + data.u_name +  ' profile" href="../users/users.php?review='+data.pid+'">';
                        str +=             data.u_name;  
                        str +=          '</a></div>';
                        str +=          '<div class="clearfix">1 review </div>';
                        str +=     '</div>';
                        str +=      '<div class="review-info clearfix">';
                        str +=      '<input type="hidden" id="dneid" value="'+data.pid+'" />';
                        str +=          ddc;
                        str +=          '<div  class="star-rating count-'+data.rating+' size-medium clearfix">';
                        str +=              '<div class="star-1"><img src="../community/shared/sprite_star.png" class="star-image" alt=""></div>';
                        str +=              '<div class="star-2"><img src="../community/shared/sprite_star.png" class="star-image" alt=""></div>';
                        str +=              '<div class="star-3"><img src="../community/shared/sprite_star.png" class="star-image" alt=""></div>';
                        str +=              '<div class="star-4"><img src="../community/shared/sprite_star.png" class="star-image" alt=""></div>';
                        str +=              '<div class="star-5"><img src="../community/shared/sprite_star.png" class="star-image" alt=""></div>';
                        str +=          '</div>';


                        var publish_date = $.timeago(data.pubdate); 
                        var publish_date = $.trim(publish_date); 


                        //  Published    Wednesday, October 24, 2012    

                        if(publish_date != "false") {
                            show_date = publish_date;
                        } 
                        else {

                            var dayNames = [
                              "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                              "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saterday"
                            ];

                            var monthNames = [
                              "January", "February", "March",
                              "April", "May", "June", "July",
                              "August", "September", "October",
                              "November", "December"
                            ];

                            var date = new Date(data.pubdate);
                            var day = date.getDate();
                            var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
                            var year = date.getFullYear();
                            var dayIndex = date.getDay();

                            var show_date = 'Published    ' + dayNames[dayIndex] + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
                        }


                        str +=      '<time datetime="'+data.pubdate+'" class="ndate timeago" title="'+data.pubdate+'" >'; 
                        str +=       show_date +    '<span title=""></span>';
                        str +=      '</time>';  

                        if (data.ref_number == 11) {
                            str +=  '<div class="hover_tip"><div class="review-verified"><div class="review-verified-tooltip-text-hidden">'+ data.u_name +' was invited to write this review by The Logo Company. <a href="https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/articles/201819697-?utm_medium=consumer&utm_source=verified_order_learn_more&utm_campaign=consumer_verified_order" rel="nofollow" class="review-verified-tooltip-link">Learn more</a>.</div><span class="icon icon-ok-sign"></span> Verified order<div class="review-verified-tooltip-container" style="width: 421px;"><p class="review-verified-tooltip-text">'+data.u_name+' was invited to write this review by The Logo Company. <a href="https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/articles/201819697-?utm_medium=consumer&utm_source=verified_order_learn_more&utm_campaign=consumer_verified_order" rel="nofollow" class="review-verified-tooltip-link">Learn more</a>.</p></div></div></div>';
                        }
                        else {

                            str +=  '<div class="hover_tip"><div class="review-verified"><div class="review-verified-tooltip-text-hidden">Thelogocompany.net were not able to verify which order correlates to this review. <a href="https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/articles/201819697-?utm_medium=consumer&utm_source=verified_order_learn_more&utm_campaign=consumer_verified_order" rel="nofollow" class="review-verified-tooltip-link">Learn more</a>.</div><span class="icon icon-ok-sign"></span> Unverified order<div class="review-verified-tooltip-container" style="width: 421px;"><p class="review-verified-tooltip-text">Thelogocompany.net were not able to verify which order correlates to this review. <a href="https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/articles/201819697-?utm_medium=consumer&utm_source=verified_order_learn_more&utm_campaign=consumer_verified_order" rel="nofollow" class="review-verified-tooltip-link">Learn more</a>.</p></div></div></div>';
                        }
                        //<span class="icon icon-ok-sign"></span>





                        str +=      '<h3 class="review-title en h4">';
                        str +=          '<a class="review-title-link" rel="nofollow" href="../reviews/reviews.php?review='+data.pid+'">';
                        str +=          data.title;                                     
                        str +=          '</a></h3><div class="review-body">';
                        str +=      data.desc;
                        str +=      '</div>';
                        str +=          '<div class="review-actions clearfix"><div class="btn-action clearfix "><div class="icon icon-thumbs-up circle-action blue-action" id="pressme_'+data.pid+'" onclick="funn('+data.pid+')"; title="Find useful" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="number-box" id="box_'+data.pid+'" style="display:none"><div class="text useful-counter-js" id="val_'+data.pid+'"></div></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" ><div class="icon icon-report circle-action notify" id='+data.pid+' title="Notify Compliance" onclick="fun('+data.pid+');"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-facebook circle circle-action social-share-facebook-js" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-google circle circle-action social-share-google-js" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-status="DanielleB gave The Logo Company 5 stars via @TrustpilotUS [Link]" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-twitter circle circle-action social-share-twitter-js" title="Share on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="review-action-response" ><ul class="reporting hide" id="report_'+data.pid+'" style="display: none;"><li class="first">Dear Guest. You just clicked on Notify Compliance because you believe that this review is violating Trustpilot’s <a href="#" class="review-guidelines" data-url="http://legal.trustpilot.com/user-guidelines">User Guidelines</a>.<br><br><i>If you are a business user and you wish to report a review on your company profile, please do so on your <a href="https://en-us.b2b.trustpilot.com/Login?goto=http%3a%2f%2fen-us.b2b.trustpilot.com%2fng%2fdashboard" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">business account</a>. Don’t have an account? It’s free and easy to <a href="http://business.trustpilot.com/signup" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">sign up</a>.</i></li><li><label for="message">Please provide us with as much information as possible in the text field provided below (min. 50 characters).</label><div class="alert alert-warning hidden">Please use a minimum of 50 characters.</div><textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control message" placeholder="Describe why you believe this review requires our Compliance Team’s attention. Does it contain e.g. defamatory statements, coarse language, or does it seem fake?"></textarea><a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/users/connect?signup=True"><input type="submit" value="Submit notification to Compliance" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg buttonsubmit-js"></a></li></ul><div class="find-useful hidden"></div></div></div></div></div>';
                        //str +=        '<div class="review-actions clearfix"><div class="btn-action clearfix "><div class="icon icon-thumbs-up circle-action blue-action" id="pressme_'+id+'" onclick="funn('+id+')"; title="Find useful" ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="number-box" id="box_'+id+'" style="display:none"><div class="text useful-counter-js" id="val_'+id+'"></div></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" ><div class="icon icon-report circle-action notify" id='+id+' title="Notify Compliance" onclick="fun('+id+');"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-facebook circle circle-action social-share-facebook-js" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-google circle circle-action social-share-google-js" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="btn-action clearfix" data-social-share-url="https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/57c5e5e20000ff000981e1be" data-status="DanielleB gave The Logo Company 5 stars via @TrustpilotUS [Link]" data-event-source="CompanyProfile" data-shared-object="SellerReview"><div class="icon icon-twitter circle circle-action social-share-twitter-js" title="Share on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div><div class="review-action-response" ><ul class="reporting hide" id="report_'+id+'" style="display: none;"><li class="first">Dear Guest./*'+username+'*/ You just clicked on Notify Compliance because you believe that this review is violating Trustpilot’s <a href="#" class="review-guidelines" data-url="http://legal.trustpilot.com/user-guidelines">User Guidelines</a>.<br><br><i>If you are a business user and you wish to report a review on your company profile, please do so on your <a href="https://en-us.b2b.trustpilot.com/Login?goto=http%3a%2f%2fen-us.b2b.trustpilot.com%2fng%2fdashboard" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">business account</a>. Don’t have an account? It’s free and easy to <a href="http://business.trustpilot.com/signup" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">sign up</a>.</i></li><li><label for="message">Please provide us with as much information as possible in the text field provided below (min. 50 characters).</label><div class="alert alert-warning hidden">Please use a minimum of 50 characters.</div><textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control message" placeholder="Describe why you believe this review requires our Compliance Team’s attention. Does it contain e.g. defamatory statements, coarse language, or does it seem fake?"></textarea><a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/users/connect?signup=True"><input type="submit" value="Submit notification to Compliance" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg buttonsubmit-js"></a></li></ul><div class="find-useful hidden"></div></div></div></div></div>';

                        $(".reviews_container").html(str); 



                            },
                            error: function(request, status, error) {
                                 console.log(error);
                              } 

                        });//inner ajax ends




                    }

                }
            });



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second bout of ajax calls are done asynchronously so they will display as soon as the results are retunred. You are essentially firing all the ajax calls one after another without waiting for any results, and showing the results as they are answered by the server.

Comment: Thanks Matt got your point. Please tell me in what way i can stop this thing ?

Comment: Okay after your suggestion i tried async: false, and it works good for now. but i still want to know the other solution. because async: false, is not the good solution.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the full app, but looping through and making ajax calls is generally a bad idea. You should be able to return all the data you need in the first ajax query. Do the heavy work in PHP, and pass through objects which hold all the information needed per "item".

Comment: Actually you are right. But i have no choice at that time and i am solving this problem from last 2 days and now i want to know the solution. Just for the knowledge. So in future i do not want to stuck again for this issue.

Comment: Your going to kill the server with that many requests if loads of people are using it. If you really have to, then save each result in an indexed array with a counter for each ajax call. Its complicated doing it that way and puts more load on the users browser to build the page